# Как найти количество файлов в подкаталоге (папки считаются за файл), начинающихся с заглавной буквы в shell Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, shell

Нужно посчитать в подкаталоге число файлов, начинающихся с заглавной буквы. Как это сделать, использую стандартные фильтры shell Unix'a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find Music/* -maxdepth 0 -type f | grep "^[[:upper:]]" | wc -l`

Ищем все файлы в текущем каталоге | Начинающиеся с большой буквы | и считаем их количество.

PS: А если ещё и папки, то ещё проще.

`find Music/* -maxdepth 0 | grep "^[[:upper:]]" | wc -l`

Или

`ls -d Music/* | grep "^[[:upper:]]" | wc -l`

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо

Comment: *Useless use of grep*... `man find`, а точнее поищите `-regex`. (ну и `-regextype`)